# VS compiled TypeScript code can't run in Chrome/FF?

Tags: iis, utf-8, visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

**Update**

> You can read all the details below.. but basically, now matter what I
>   do VS2012 Typescript is compiling and saving ANSI files...
>
> I can manually resave the files as UTF-8 and everything works fine..
>
> I am on Windows 8, and I have reproduced this issue on 5 different
>   machines used by 5 different developers in 3 different cities...
>
> The only commonality is Windows 8

I have a sample project that works great in IE but not at all in Chrome or FF. It looks like the files are being encoded improperly and IE is figuring it out but Chrome and FF aren't...

For example, here are the first few likes of a compiled JavaScript file

```
/// <reference path="../Framework/Core.ts" /> 
var MVVM; 
(function (MVVM) {
var Application = (function () {
    function Application() {
        this.core = undefined;
        this.templatePath = "Atlatl/Templates/";
        this.viewPath = "Atlatl/Views/";
        this.dependentScriptsPath = "Scripts/";
        this.viewModelsPath = "Atlatl/App/ViewModels/";
        this.frameworkPath = "Atlatl/Framework/";
        this.pages = {
        };
```

and here is what Chrome "thinks" its receiving from IIS (8 & 8 express) :

> 爼晥牥湥散瀠瑡㵨⸢⼮牆浡睥牯⽫潃敲琮≳⼠ാ瘊牡䴠噖㭍਍昨湵瑣潩⁮䴨噖⥍笠਍††慶⁲灁汰捩瑡潩⁮‽昨湵瑣潩⁮⤨笠

Update

And here are the headers from the chrome call for the file

-- Request --

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:40665
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 03 Apr 2013 16:33:17 GMT
If-None-Match:"153551f28830ce1:0"
Referer:http://localhost:40665/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
```

--Response--

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Date:Wed, 03 Apr 2013 17:06:28 GMT
ETag:"153551f28830ce1:0"
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcUmFuZG9tV29ya1xNdmNBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjEyXE12Y0FwcGxpY2F0aW9uMTJcQXRsYXRsXEFwcFxhcHAuanM=?=
```

nothing too funny in there...

I have tried all the following compilation methods with various failures, all along the same lines

1) Just using the TypeScript compiler in VS

2) Using Web Essentials

A) With and without UTF-8 BOM flags set to true

B) With and without recompiling on build

I can provide a sample project, or if you go through this tutorial you will see what I am talking about https://github.com/CatapultSystems/atlatl/wiki/Visual-studio-hello-world

I am totally stumped as to what could be causing this... and am all ears as to what's up..

Comment: The file is encoded the same, it's the interpretation that's different. The mojibake is UTF-16 interpretation of your file. What causes the browser to interpret your files in UTF-16? For example the HTTP Content-Type header sent from your server.

Comment: I'll post the headers Chrome is sending/receiving.. nothing to funky there..

Comment: What about the main page? Btw you are looking for `Content-Type` in the response headers, no need to post them all :P

Comment: main HTML loads fine, other javascript (headJS, jquery, etc, all load fine)

Comment: Ok then I have one last option.. if you open the javascript file with a hex editor, do you see the bytes `0xFF 0xFE` at the start of the file?

Comment: This also happens in the visual studio 2012 debug webserver (not IIS 8  Express) so its not the web server.. its the generated file.

If I open the JS files in notepad, and re-save them as UTF-8 they work fine... But that't not a solution that's a diagnosis that the problem is in the file being saved...

Comment: Nope, file starts with 2F 2F ("//" comment lines starts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is anything related with the compilation or TypeScript.

The generated JavaScript files are OK without the BOM.

The response should contain `Content-Length: XXXX` and `Content-Type: application/javascript` - and yours does not. It seems a `304 Not Modified` response instead than a `200 OK` one.

Have you tried to force a refresh in Chrome using Ctrl+F5 ?

**UPDATE**

Re-saving in notepad the JavaScript file selecting UTF-8 just adds the BOM (assuming that the content of the JS file is 7 bit ASCII).

You should be able to produce the same effect setting Web Essentials to add the BOM, or adding a dummy string constant

```
var dummyChars = "Ù";
```

to your TypeScript file. After you do this the JavaScript file should be identical to the one generated saving from Notepad.

Comment: Yes, multiple times, and when I get 200's I still get gibberish... The key point is if I open the file in notepad, do a "Save as" select UTF-8 (it will say ANSI) and save the file.  It will load properly.. Its not server related, if it were server related then it wouldn't happen in IIS, IIS Express and Dev Webserver (all on my local box non of them have every had any tweaking done to them, and it defiantly wouldn't happen on 5 different users computers in 3 separate cities.... all building and testing there own projects.

Comment: Mystery - it works for me - I added some more guesses to my answer above

Comment: I am running Windows 8, VS 2012 Ultimate Update 2 CPT, TS 0.8.3.1, Web Essentials 2.6.... Looks like there might be a new CPT for Update 2, so I am going to install that and see if it fixes it.. But I don't think the other devs with the problem are on Update 2 so....

Comment: adding that dummy var works... it shouldn't but it does... thats one hacky work around... but it proves the issue is in VS somewhere..

Comment: I'd not say that - it proves that having the BOM in the JS files fixes the problem, and that is a hacky way to have the BOM. It is not clear why the BOM is needed in your situation - it works fine for me without it (and I suppose for many others, otherwise this problem should be much more common)